# Melting a pandas DataFrame into dictionary with unique keys based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame in Python3.x

```
import pandas as pd

key_dict = {"coordinates": ["AB1", "AB1", "AB1",  "AB1", "AC1", "AC1", "AD1", ...], "start": [762, 23, 75, 98, 1274, 1587, 1991, ...], "end": [2481, 238, 340, 375, 1789, 1689, 2211, ...] }

df = pd.DataFrame(key_dict)

print(df)
  coordinates  start   end
0         AB1    762  2481
1         AB1     23   238
2         AB1     75   340
3         AB1     98   375
4         AC1   1274  1789
5         AC1   1587  1689
6         AD1   1991  2211
...       ...         ...
```

Now, to convert this to a (nested) dictionary is simple, e.g.

```
my_dict = df.to_dict()
print(my_dict)

{'coordinates': {0: 'AB1', 1: 'AB1', 2: 'AB1', 3: 'AB1', 4: 'AC1', 5: 'AC1', 6: 'AD1'}, 
    'end': {0: 2481, 1: 238, 2: 340, 3: 375, 4: 1789, 5: 1689, 6: 2211}, 
    'start': {0: 762, 1: 23, 2: 75, 3: 98, 4: 1274, 5: 1587, 6: 1991}}
```

The column names are the keys to the main dictionary, and each index is the key to the subset dictionaries.

I would prefer a nested dictionary the unique element in `coordinates` to be the dictionary key, and the elements are the values.

In the example above, this would be:

```
{"AB1": {"start": [762, 23, 75, 98], "end":[2481, 238, 340, 375]}, 
    "AC1":{"start": [1274, 1587], "end":[1789, 1689]}, "AD1":{"start": [1991], "end":[2211]}, ...}
```

Somehow, one would have to remove indices, and ignore the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly convoluted approach, but can be done with a little dataframe reshaping with `groupby`.

```
df = df.groupby('coordinates').agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).T
df

coordinates                    AB1           AC1     AD1
end          [2481, 238, 340, 375]  [1789, 1689]  [2211]
start            [762, 23, 75, 98]  [1274, 1587]  [1991]
```

```
df.to_dict()

{
    "AC1": {
        "start": [
            1274,
            1587
        ],
        "end": [
            1789,
            1689
        ]
    },
    "AD1": {
        "start": [
            1991
        ],
        "end": [
            2211
        ]
    },
    "AB1": {
        "start": [
            762,
            23,
            75,
            98
        ],
        "end": [
            2481,
            238,
            340,
            375
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convoluted?

Comment: @EB2127 In the sense, that there isn't any simpler way to get to your output. The thing is, is it worth the trouble to reshape your data? If yes, then this is probably the _least_ convoluted answer one can give :-)